# Structures, malloc.. I couldn't be more confused

Tags: c, malloc, structure

Here is the whole code I have so far for the assignment I am having trouble with:

```
// This program takes a quadratic from the user, and prints the solution(s) if they exist. 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>


// Define quadratic structure 

typedef struct quadratic{
    float a, b, c;
    float discriminant;
    float real_root_1;
    float real_root_2;
    float complex_root;
} Quadratic;

// 'Redefine' malloc to also check allocation of memory when called, as suggested 

void xmalloc(size_t n){
    void *p = malloc(n);
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("\n ERROR: Unable to allocate memory! \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return p;
}

// Following example code in lecture notes 

Quadratic *newquadratic() {

    Quadratic *q = xmalloc(sizeof *q);


    return q;
}



int main () {

    return 0;
}
```

Now I'm not too sure what I'm doing, but I'll ask about that after the problem this code has first. On the "Quadratic *q = xmalloc()" line I get the error "Void value not ignored as it ought to be", however this code was basically copied out the lecture notes and the variables names changed! (as we were suggested to do..). I tried removing the void tags in xmalloc, which then started complaining of undefined variables, so I'm really not sure what's going on.

More generally, I'm confused as hell about some parts of this: Namely, the function "Quadratic *newquadratic()". Why the hell is there a star there!? How can a pointer be a function..? Not only that, but it would seem if I remove the star, everything is ok only if I star the return, "return *p;". It would seem that this function can only return pointers, but I defined Quadratic as a variable type (structure), so.. why would it want to return a pointer rather than a 'quadratic'?

Comment: Your `xmalloc` function doesn't return anything - the only thing it does is leak memory. Please read a good C book to get the hang of functions and return values before you try to tackle pointers and malloc.

Comment: @Mat I had a return p; in there before, which gave me a warning "dereferencing 'void *' pointer". Since it's a void function I thought it probably doesn't need a return, so i deleted it, and it didn't complain..

Also, having the return there doesn't rid the original problem!

Comment: Well, as I said, you're missing fundamentals. If you want it to return something, it can't be a void function. And since you're using its return value, then you do want it to return something. If you don't know what `*` means besides a type name, you have no hope of getting any of this to work except by iterative guessing. Do re-read all your basic lectures and follow a book.

Comment: Take a good C book, such as "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie, the creators of the language. It's not long by today's standards, and it will answer all your questions in a very clear way.

Comment: @Mat So what exactly should the type of a function that deals with general pointers be then? To me, * is an operator such that *p is the value of whatever is stored in the memory address p. From that, having *function as a function makes no sense to me.

Comment: And that's why you need to re-read your lectures or get a book - you don't seem to understand function declaration syntax, which tells me you're probably also missing a good understanding of pointer variable declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As things currently stand you xmalloc() function is useless. It allocates memory but does not return anything so no-one can use the allocated memory.

Possibly you made a transcription error:

```
void * xmalloc(size_t n){
    void *p = malloc(n);
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("\n ERROR: Unable to allocate memory! \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return p;
}
```

If you have xmalloc declared as returning a void* you can then return something and use it in the calling function.

The implication to me is that you don't understand the difference between a **void** and a **void***. A function returning a void is returning nothing, there is no value to use. A void* on the other hand is a pointer to **anything**, and hence is a great representation of a generally useful block of memery allocated by malloc.

Comment: This is what I had originally. It doesn't work. The return generates a warning, calling this function generates an error. You're right, though. I didn't know that difference.

Comment: This is correct, what error does it give? I can see no reason why the return statement should give any error. Possibly the assignment statement might in the calling function may have a problem, but let's deal with that once this function works.

Comment: Yeah, I've gotten it to work now, the it said the error was there, but the error in the code was elsewhere! Thank you very much for your help. If you could clear up one more thing for me that would be fantastic; I recall that if p is a pointer, then \*p is the value of the data stored at p, or if q is some data it is stored at &q. Now why is it Void\* that deals with the pointer, rather than Void&? Void* p =malloc() looks like its trying to allocate memory to a value, rather than a place for a pointer to point to. Void& p = malloc looks more "right" to me, assigning a pointer its memory..

Comment: (void*) is the syntax to cast whatever is to its right to void*. Now, you want a pointer to void (to your allocated memory, viewed as void), so you need to write void*, which is the C syntax to declare a pointer to void.

Comment: & is the take the address of operator, you can't (in C as opposed to C++) declare anything of type "take the address of". * is used in two ways: when declaring a variable int * pi; char * pc; or, void * pv; in each case we are saying here the variable is a "pointer to something". The second way is when we use the pointer and look at what it's pointing to. So when we say int anInt = *pi; we are saying grab the int pi is pointing to and assign it.

Answer (score 0):

`xmalloc` should return a pointer if you're using it like `malloc`.
Then you use it so allocate N bytes of memory for a `Quadratic` structure.

Comment: It originally had a return.. see my comment to Mat.

Comment: Please post the original, unmodified code.

Comment: The return was all I removed. It is there now.